# Why is xmlWriter writing ASCII characters in the output xml file?

Tags: c#, xml

Here's how I set up my xmlWriter and xmlWriterSettings:

```
        XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        settings.Encoding.Equals("UTF-8"); 
        settings.Indent = true;
        settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
        settings.NewLineOnAttributes = true;           
        settings.CheckCharacters = true;
        settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = false;

        XmlWriter xmlWriter =  XmlWriter.Create(otptFile,settings);
```

I produce a file that looks like a valid xml file, but when I run it through a validator I get an error: ascii "\EF" does not map to unicode.

If I open this file in textpad and just save it, this error goes away and the file is valid.

I am using streamReader to read in an ascii file. I checked if I needed to set something in the streamreader declaration, but from what I understand UTF-8 is the default.

I am trying to understand why my program has ascii values if I have set the encoding to UTF-8 and how I can get rid of the easily in my code. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

The byte sequence `0xEF,0xBB,0xBF` is the UTF-8 [byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) (BOM).

If you don't want to output the BOM, set the [Encoding property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.encoding.aspx) to an [UTF8Encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31d6tdy7.aspx) instance with the *encoderShouldEmitUTF8Identifier* [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s064f8w2.aspx) argument set to `false`:

```
settings.Encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false);
```